# How to programatically send openoffice writer odt file to printer from C# Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I'd like to send an OpenOffice writer document to the default printer from within a C# WinForms application.  The purpose is to print customer receipts. I plan on opening a prepared OpenOffice file, substitute dynamic customer information and then print the modified document.  It is important that OO not necessarily be installed so solutions which depend on OO or open up an OO prompt won't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too use open office for printing customer generated invoices, I do so in bulk and below is the method that I use.

What you are seeking is achievable by using "ProcessStartInfo" from the Systems.Diagnostics namespace found here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

the important part is ensuring you have set "CreateNoWindow" to true as well as settings the "WindowStyle" to "ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden".

Simply pass in the location of the file to print, and ensure you include the file extension after the location. I use this snippet regularly so if you have any problems just let me know.

```
void printDoc(String fileLocation) {
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(fileLocation);
    info.Verb = "print";
    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
    info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    Process.Start(info);
}
```